# Find supported video formats of android device programmatically

Tags: android, android-video-player

Is there a way to find the android device supported video formats programmatically from an Android application?
Is there any android inbuilt library for the same?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "supported video formats". Supported for... what?

Comment: "Supported video formats" meaning the the video formats which can be supported by the android devices for the video playback.